# TapGesture is not working in Xcode 11.0 Beta

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-catalina

Playing around with SwiftUI and this TapGesture() (or any other gesture) doesn't seem to work for me in a Cocoa app for MacOS, despite `@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)` when I View Definition on TapGesture.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CircleView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
            .gesture(
                TapGesture()
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        print("View tapped!")
                }
            )
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct CircleView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleView()
    }
}
#endif
```

The Build succeeded, I'm viewing the Circle in Preview and I have the console open, but nothing seems to print.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a 10.15 Beta bug? Is there another framework I need to import other than SwiftUI? New to Swift here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tap is working fine, but when you’re previewing the app, you won’t see your `print` statements in the console. Actually run the app and you’ll see the `print` statements show up in your console.

Or change your app to present something in the UI confirming the tap gesture, e.g., an `Alert`:

```
struct CircleView : View {
    @State var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .tapAction {
                self.showAlert = true
            }
            .presentation($showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("View Tapped!"),
                      primaryButton: .default(Text("OK")),
                      secondaryButton: .cancel())
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps you would want to animate the change of color of the shape:

```
struct CircleView: View {
    @State var isBlue = true

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isBlue ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            .tapAction {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isBlue.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```